# solving the cumulative function (CDF) using R

Tags: r, statistics, cdf

usually any package of any distribution in R contains three commands as for normal distribution we have rnorm, dnorm and pnorm. I found a package called kdevine [enter link description here](https://github.com/tnagler/kdevine)

and it has dkdevinecop and rkdevinecop but it doesn't have the option pkdevinecop (the CDF).
I tried to write it like this but it is wrong, could somebody see it please

```
library(kdevine)
library(kdecopula)

data(wdbc)

fit <- kdevine(wdbc[, 5:7], xmin = rep(0, 3))
f<-dkdevine(wdbc[, 5:7], fit)

for(i in 1:length(f)){
 p<-sum(dkdevinecop(c(wdbc[, 5],wdbc[,6],wdbc[,7]),fit))
 }
  print (p)
```

Comment: `f <- sort(f);
cdf <- cumsum(f)/sum(f);
plot(cdf)`
Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: perhaps you mean any of these functions? `dke1d(), pkde1d(), rkde1d(): Density, cdf, and simulation functions`.

Comment: Thanks @Merijn van Tilborg actually these functions dke1d(), pkde1d(), rkde1d() are the marginals (of one variable).